# Is it mandatory to always send dummy OUT packet to maintain AOA connection?

Tags: android, usb, stm32

I am developping Android Open Accessory class over USB and I seeing what looks bizarre.
In fact I succeeded to establish connection between STM32 microocntroller and android device (switching the andorid device in accesory mode)
Now I am stuck in communcation phase between STM32 microcontroller and Android device (Galaxy S3 in my case). In fact, I am discovering that I **must** always send dummy buffer so that the smartphone doesn't disconnect. Is that expected for you ?

Comment: After some tests, it seems to be yes the microsontroller must always send USB DIN token and USB DOUT token

Comment: Then you should post this as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not true that the smartphone must always send dummy buffer to keep the connection.
From USB point of view, the communcation is based on bulk endpoint: In such case the host doesn't need to send dummy byte to keep the device connected.